# Rotina com FireBase

Tags: firebase

É possível configurar uma rotina para um banco de dados em firebase?

Em hospedagens de sites e dbs temos, geralmente, a opção de deixar um arquivo php ou outro, por exemplo, que a cada x horas execute seu script, eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso com firebase, configurar algum arquivo que a cada x horas faça uma busca e então modifique alguns campos.